# Curve with orthogonal increments (Papa Rudin: Chapter 4 Exercise 17)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Here is the problem presented by Walter Rudin in his [Real and Complex  Analysis](https://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/real-and-complex-analysis.pdf) book (chapter 4 exercise 17).

> 17. Show that there is a continuous one-to-one mapping $\gamma$ of $[0,1]$ into $H$ such that $\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)$ is orthogonal to $\gamma(d)-\gamma(c)$ whenever $0\leq a\leq b\leq c \leq d \leq 1$. ($\gamma$ may be called a "curve with orthogonal increments.") Hint: Take $H=L^2$, and consider characteristic functions of certain subsets of $[0,1]$.

My question is how is this true? I have shown that the hint works but it doesn't seem to generalize to abstract hilbert spaces.

> Proof(Hint): Assume that $H=L^2$ then define $\gamma(x)=\chi_{[0,x]}$ then it is clear that $$(\gamma(b)-\gamma(a),\gamma(d)-\gamma(c))=(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\chi_{(a,b]}\overline{\chi_{(c,d]}}dm)^{\frac{1}{2}}=(m((a,b]\cap (c,d]))^{\frac{1}{2}}=0$$ It is also clear that $\gamma$ one-to-one and continuous.

But as a possible counterexample take for instance the hilbert space $(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})$. It seems to me that to find a function $\gamma$ satisfying the given conditions would mean that $$(\gamma(b)-\gamma(a),\gamma(d)-\gamma(c))=(\gamma(b)-\gamma(a))\overline{(\gamma(d)-\gamma(c))}=0$$

This would imply that $\gamma(b)=\gamma(a)$ or $\gamma(d)=\gamma(c)$ a contradiction to the one-to-one condition. (Hell if we drop that condition just map the entire space to the 0 vector and we are done.)

Comment: And what is his functional analysis book called ? Grandpapa Rudin ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Oh nevermind the previous response. Please lets not have an offtopic memey conversation here. I really need the help.

Comment: Congratulations! You have found an error in Rudin's book. I think Rudin assumed that H was infinite dimensional ( in which case it contains a copy of $L^{2}$.